# Modify element tabindex order

Tags: html, tabindex

I have a website and I'm making it available for keyboard users. This might have been asked before but I haven't found a way to make it work yet. :(

The issues that I'm having is that on a certain point there is a slideshow and a pauze/play link. When a users tabs through the site, he first has to go through the entire slideshow and then the focus lands on the pauze/play link.

I've tried recreating it as best and simple as possible.

[**Fiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/3RYYe/2/)

When you tab through the elements you notice that the focus goes directly on the slides and afterwards goes to the pauze/play link. I know this is normal behaviour because of the HTML structure.

My question is: How can I manipulate this order that whenever I tab from the last "link" the focus goes straight to the pauze/play instead of going to the slides.

I've tried messing around with `tabindex="0 / 1";` but then I need to put this on all the elements?

(sidenote: *on the website are a lot more HTML elements above this 'slideshow' and I cannot change the structure that is given*)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only way to change this order is to reorder your HTML elements.

`tabindex` itself can do 2 things:

- it sets the order of "focusable" elements
- it makes element "focusable".

`tabindex = -1`  Element will not get focus
`tabindex = 0`   Element will be focusable in the normal tab (semantic) order
`tabindex = 1`   Element with positive values will be focused first

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to change the tab selection without using `tabindex` (or JavaScript).

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3RYYe/3/)

Comment: Is this possible without putting the tabindex on every element?

Comment: As I said, no. You could set it through JavaScript but that would make no sense regarding accessibility.

Comment: So the only option that I have here is to try and change the HTML structure?

Comment: Yes, you need to specify the tabindexes in your html structure.

Comment: I mean the order of the HTML elements in the DOM, because I cannot put a tabindex on every element

Comment: I upvoted it, not accept cause I cannot use the solution you provided.